# Linq Lowest Unique Value or Lowest Row and Column Value Whichever Exact match or Partial Match Whichever is Value is smaller

Tags: vb.net, linq

Hello I'm trying to develop a Linq query to find the Lowest Unique Value or Lowest Value also sorted by Row and Column Value.
First it does the Lowest Unique Value Exact match (unique value)
If nothing is found then it does a Partial Match (lowest value then lowest row then column) 
Whichever has the smallest Value is the output (unique or not found).

Table of Data

| Row | Column | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 0 | 2 | 2 |

The output should be the last data in the table `0,2,2` since it has the lowest Row and it's a duplicate Value (row 1 and row 0).

if you add Data `2,0,0` (Value of 0) would overrule the duplicate Values (`2's`).

| Row | Column | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |

```
   Structure FoundValue
        Dim Value As Short
        Dim Row As Integer
        Dim Column As Integer
    End Structure
  
   Dim UniqueValuesFound As New List(Of Short)
   Dim ValuesFoundInPath As New List(Of FoundValue)

   UniqueValuesFound.Add(0)
   UniqueValuesFound.Add(2)
   UniqueValuesFound.Add(3)

   Dim foundValue As New FoundValue
   foundValue.Value = 2
   foundValue.Row = 1
   foundValue.Column = 1
   ValuesFoundInPath.Add(foundValue)

   foundValue = New FoundValue
   foundValue.Value = 3
   foundValue.Row = 0
   foundValue.Column = 2
   ValuesFoundInPath.Add(foundValue)

   foundValue = New FoundValue
   foundValue.Value = 2
   foundValue.Row = 0
   foundValue.Column = 2
   ValuesFoundInPath.Add(foundValue)

   'foundValue = New FoundValue
   'foundValue.Value = 0
   'foundValue.Row = 2
   'foundValue.Column = 0
   'ValuesFoundInPath.Add(foundValue)

'New Attempt
    Dim alreadyFound As Boolean = False

    Dim matching = ValuesFoundInPath.Where(Function(s)
                                               Dim index As Integer = UniqueValuesFound.BinarySearch(s.Value)
                                               If alreadyFound = False AndAlso index >= 0 Then
                                                   alreadyFound = True
                                                   Return True 'UniqueValuesFound(index) 'exact match
                                               ElseIf alreadyFound = False AndAlso index < 0 Then
                                                   alreadyFound = True
                                                   Return True 's.Value
                                               Else
                                                   Return False
                                               End If
                                           End Function).OrderBy(Function(p) p.Value).ThenBy(Function(p) p.Row).ThenBy(Function(p) p.Column)
```

```
    'New Attempt
        Dim alreadyFound As Boolean = False

        Dim matching = ValuesFoundInPath.Where(Function(s)
                                                   Dim index As Integer = UniqueValuesFound.BinarySearch(s.Value)
                                                   If alreadyFound = False AndAlso index >= 0 Then
                                                       alreadyFound = True
                                                       Return True 'UniqueValuesFound(index) 'exact match
                                                   ElseIf alreadyFound = False AndAlso index < 0 Then
                                                       alreadyFound = True
                                                       Return True 's.Value
                                                   Else
                                                       Return False
                                                   End If
                                               End Function).OrderBy(Function(p) p.Value).ThenBy(Function(p) p.Row).ThenBy(Function(p) p.Column)
```

Look at `'New Attempt` code it speaks itself, what I'm trying to do is find the first value which has a exact match in `UniqueValuesFound` and if it cannot find the value in `UniqueValuesFound` array then default to spitting out a partial match lowest value it can find. The array `ValuesFoundInPath` contains all the values in a random order as well as Column and Row types, which have to be sorted for partial match to find the lowest Row first.

Comment: can someone help with `matching` `'New Attempt` code it looks perfect but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't think anyone would understand what you are asking.

Comment: Look at `'New Attempt` code it speaks itself, what I'm trying to do is find the first value which has a exact match in `UniqueValuesFound` and if it cannot find the value in `UniqueValuesFound` array then default to spitting out a partial match lowest value it can find. The array `ValuesFoundInPath` contains all the values in a random order as well as Column and Row types, which have to be sorted for partial match to find the lowest Row first.

Comment: It doesn't. Anyway, it is up to you to explain your problem with a good sample or not.

Comment: Yes the sample code is good you can compile it just fine.. and add breakpoint to `matching` to see the results. I explained it better, sorry for the mix up.

Comment: OK good luck with that.

Comment: I might of fixed it with a single Boolean variable the code lambda was getting ran too much times instead of just 1 time. Although the results from `matching` is yielding no results which is strange because in debugging I do return a `True` which should return the value regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally Solved It!, needed to use `Find` instead of `Where` and problem disappeared!.

The answer now requires 2 linq queries instead of one cannot do chaining on `Find`

```
    ValuesFoundInPath = ValuesFoundInPath.OrderBy(Function(p) p.Value).ThenBy(Function(p) p.Row).ThenBy(Function(p) p.Column).ToList()

    Dim alreadyFound As Boolean = False

    Dim matching = ValuesFoundInPath.Find(Function(s)
                                              Dim index As Integer = UniqueValuesFound.BinarySearch(s.Value)
                                              If alreadyFound = False AndAlso index >= 0 Then
                                                  alreadyFound = True
                                                  Return True 'UniqueValuesFound(index) 'exact match
                                              ElseIf alreadyFound = False AndAlso index < 0 Then
                                                  alreadyFound = True
                                                  Return True 's.Value
                                              Else
                                                  Return False
                                              End If
                                          End Function)

    Dim result As New Result
    result.Answer = matching.Value
    result.CurrentRow = matching.Row
    result.CurrentColumn = matching.Column
```

You may have problems since `Find(...)` pre-sorts the list of values always. So you need to use `FindIndex(...)` this avoids the sorting issue.

```
    Dim matchingIndex = ValuesFoundInPath.FindIndex(Function(s)
                                                        Dim index As Integer = UniqueValuesFound.BinarySearch(s.Value)
                                                        If alreadyFound = False AndAlso index >= 0 Then
                                                            alreadyFound = True
                                                            Return True 'UniqueValuesFound(index) 'exact match
                                                        ElseIf alreadyFound = False AndAlso index < 0 Then
                                                            alreadyFound = True
                                                            Return True 's.Value
                                                        End If
                                                        Return False 'No match.
                                                    End Function)

    If matchingIndex < 0 Then MessageBox.Show("Wtf!")

    Dim result As New Result
    result.Answer = ValuesFoundInPath(matchingIndex).Value
    result.CurrentRow = ValuesFoundInPath(matchingIndex).Row
    result.CurrentColumn = ValuesFoundInPath(matchingIndex).Column
```

It makes the `OrderBy(...)` useless because `Find(...)` pre-sorts the lists by incrementing values.